# Storing all URL into one file

Tags: iphone, ios, class, url, nsobject

I need some help on how to reference from a class to get the `NSString` contained in that class. Reason for so is that I wish to store all the URLs that I'm using into a class so that in the event whereby there is a change in URL etc, I could just change it in one file instead of changing it one by one in all the classes.

Any idea where should I start??Firstly, should I create `NSObject` or `NSDocument` to store the URLs?Then, do I actually have to create pushController to push the string content to each of the other classes?

Sorry if my question sounds messy, I'm quite lost. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I can answer your question, but I need to know two things first.

Comment: 1. Is this a temporary store (used to transfer data while using the application; it will disappear when the user quits)  or a persistant store (it will be there next time the user opens the app)

Comment: 2. Are these urls in an array (a list of objects, accessed by the number for the index in the array) or a dictionary (objects assigned to a key: a string that is used to refer to a specific piece of information)

Comment: @WolfLink Hmm. It will actually be hardcode URL string. It must be there everytime in order for the connection to the URL to work. For the second question, it's actually in just NSString, therefore I can get the URL just by placing the variable. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create NSObject class and then place your URL in it and then access it and use it where you want.

in h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Config : NSObject {

}

//configuration section... 
extern  NSString        *SiteURL;
extern  NSString        *SiteAPIURL;

@end
```

in .m

```
#import "Config.h"

@implementation Config
//live
NSString        *SiteURL                = @"http://www.yoururl.com/";
NSString        *SiteAPIURL             = @"http://www.yoururl.com/";

@end
```

in Prefix.pch just import it `#import "Config.h"`

and use it in the class where you want to use

```
NSString *apiURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@login.php",SiteAPIURL];
```

Comment: Thanks.. But how do I actually access the SiteURL from other classes?

Comment: I did exactly as above but I can't find the .h file to import in my prefix.pch T_T

Comment: just type #import "Config.h" in Prefix.pch....under #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

Comment: I typed it in but when I tried to retrieve the URL, I typed in the variable but it gave me an error, "use of undeclared identifier"

Comment: Oh gosh I'm so sorry! I had a typo some where and it's working! Thanks so much!

Comment: Haha.. I'm not really a iPhone developer actually. I'm just a student and handling all sorts of programming~ :)

Comment: get me at rajneesh071@gmail.com

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen this before, with extern, and I would have thought the second part wouldn't compile as the code is outside of any function.  I would have suggested using properties as strings, or an NSDictionary if there were many urls, or NSUserDefaults if it needed persistance.